# array group single and duplicates

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have my array looping and building this columns :
[page link](http://www.toppromomkt.com/?wallet=dezembro-2015),

i want to group the users if they repeat, i have this number for each on row (pid) i want that all the PID with the same number to group.

maybe with some kida of if statement i can add classes to duplicates and singles in array! please help

```
// $strSQL = "SELECT *, SUM(totalparcial) as Soma FROM bruno_wallet GROUP BY nome "; 
$strSQL = "SELECT * from bruno_wallet GROUP BY id ORDER BY nome ASC "; 

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
// Each row will be made into an array ($row1) using mysql_fetch_array
$sum = 0;
$data = array();
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $events = array_unique($row1);
    $data[] = $events;

}

//now loop over data instead of mysql_fetch_array
foreach ($data as $events) {
    $currentPID = $events[12];

    echo "<div  id='linha_$events[0]' class='cor promotora_$events[12] cf'>";    

    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[0]}</div>";  //id
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[7]}</div>";  //foto
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[3]}</div>";  //data
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[2]}</div>";      //nome
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[12]}</div>";  
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[4]}</div>";  //evento
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[5]}</div>";  //horario
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[6]}</div>";  //obs
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[10]}h</div>"; //horas
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[9]}€</div>";  //valor hora
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[1]}</div>";  //Props
    echo "<div class='tb1'>{$events[8]}</div>"; //tparcial 

    echo "</div>";

    ?>
```

Comment: if you already use group by than is there any need to use array_unique

Comment: If the field `id` has distinct values (it is `PK` or `UNIQUE INDEX` on table `bruno_wallet`) then `GROUP BY` doesn't have any effect on your query. If it's not unique then your query is incorrect. `SELECT * ... GROUP BY ...` is not valid SQL, even if `MySQL` accepts it ([until version 5.7.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me :

```
     if (in_array($currentPID, $checkedPIDs)) {
   // build multiples

        } else { 


   //     build unikcs 
        array_push($checkedPIDs, $currentPID);  ?>
```